# Docker container to use same Nexus volume?

Tags: docker, nexus, docker-volume, nexus3

I run the following:

```
mkdir /some/dir/nexus-data && chown -R 200 /some/dir/nexus-data
chown -R 200 /Users/user.name/dockerVolume/nexus
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v /some/dir/nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
```

Now lets say I upload an artifact to Nexus, and stop the nexus container.

If I want another Nexus container open, on port 8082, what Docker command do I run such that **it uses the same volume as on port 8081** (so when I run this container, **it already contains the artifact** that I uploaded before)

Basically, I want both Nexus containers to **use the same storage**, so that if I upload an artifact to one port, the other port will also have it.

I ran this command, but it didn't seem to work:

```
docker run --name=nexus2 -p 8082:8081 --volumes-from nexus sonatype/nexus3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) which is what you're using as a "volume" has limited functionality as compared to an explicit Docker volume.

I believe the `--volumes-from` flag only works with volumes managed by Docker.

In order to share the volume between containers with this flag you can have docker create a volume for you with your run command.

**Example:**

`$ docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v nexus-volume:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3`

The above command will create a Docker managed volume for you with the name `nexus-volume`. You can view the details of the created volume with the command `$ docker volume inspect nexus-volume`.

Now when you want to run a second container with the same volume you can use the `--volumes-from` command as you desire.

So doing:

`$ docker run --name=nexus2 -p 8082:8081 --volumes-from nexus sonatype/nexus3`

Should give you your desired behaviour.

Comment: Unforunately this does not work. It tells me `Nexus data directory already in use :/nexus-data`